# How To Explain the Phenomenon of predict.lm in R

Tags: r

```
n = 10 #number of points
i = 1:n
x = (i-1)/n 
set.seed(777)
e = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
y = sin(2*pi*x) + e #the true model
curve_x_true = pretty(c(0, 0.9), 100) # a sequence of points used to draw the sin graph
curve_y_true = sin(2*pi*curve_x_true) # a sequence of points used to draw the sin graph
m.x = data.frame(as.matrix(poly(x, 9))) # polynomial matrix
poly.fit = lm(y~., data = m.x) # the fitted model
par(mfrow=c(2,3))

for (p in c(10, 100, 1000)){
  curve_x = pretty(c(0, 0.9), p) # a sequence of points used to draw poly graph
  plot(x, y)
  curve_hat_y = predict(poly.fit, 
                        newdata = data.frame(poly(curve_x, 9)), 
                        type = "response")
  lines(curve_x_true, curve_y_true, col = "red", lwd = 3)
  lines(curve_x, curve_hat_y, col = 'blue', lwd = 2)
}

for (p in 1:3){
  plot(y, 
       predict(poly.fit), 
       xlab = "True Value", 
       ylab = "Fitted Value", lwd = 2)
}
```

What I did in the code is using sin function and rnorm function to generate a sequence of points in order to practice polynomial regression. What is strange is that when I try to plot the predict line of poly regression using `lines()` and `predict()`, different numbers of points plot apparently different shape of graph. Also, as the number of points increases, the graph becomes more smooth, which is confusing. Is there anyone who can explain the phenomenon? Thank you very much!

[image]